# Unable to start activity when adding requestWindowFeature()

Tags: android

I'm an Android beginner，and I have written an extremely simple project. All is Ok. But when I wrote `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` the project failed in running. IDE told me that I wrote it after `setContentView` but in fact I wrote it exactly before `setContentView`. I have tried clicking "clean project" and "restart IDE" but it still happens.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

logcat:

```
02-25 18:09:48.447    2908-2908/com.wecan.wecanclub D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-25 18:09:48.451    2908-2908/com.wecan.wecanclub E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wecan.wecanclub, PID: 2908
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wecan.wecanclub/com.wecan.wecanclub.MainActivity}:
```

Comment: Post some code please!

Comment: In addition to the code, please post the Java stack trace.

Comment: Betting Tip: 1000-1 odds that the "bug" observed is in the (ie. your) code or understanding. Avoid using "bug" in titles or questions without *extensive* testing and case validation.

Answer (score 2):

Move `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate();`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**EDIT**

That title is Action Bar.

You can hide title and action bar programmatically:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {

            actionBar.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use styles:

styles.xml:

```
 <resources>

     <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
          <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
          <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     </style>

 </resources>
```

Activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

---

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Comment: After I fix the code,activity can start successfully BUT the title comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use style:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in activity add before super.onCreate():

```
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

Or in android manifest to your activity add android:theme property:

```
<activity android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
(...)
</activity>
```